# Objective c: All selectors of instance during runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List selectors for obj-c object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330030/list-selectors-for-obj-c-object)

Does anybody know how to get all selectors that a instance respond to during runtime in objective C?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [List selectors for obj-c object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330030/list-selectors-for-obj-c-object)

Comment: Do you mean all selectors actually responded to during one specific run, OR all selectors that could be responded to, determined at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330030/list-selectors-for-obj-c-object), `#import < objc/runtime.h >` and use [class_copyMethodList()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't take superclasses into account....

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is not possible. "The selectors an instance responds to" may be an infinite set. For example, it is possible to implement a class that is sent Roman numerals as messages and returns the corresponding integer value. If you want to know the precise set of *instance methods* implemented by a class at a given time (which is a different question), you can just use the [Objective-C runtime functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) to get a class's instance method list and walk up the class tree to find the ones it inherits from superclasses. Again, though, these are two totally different things. A class might have a method for a message that it chooses not to respond to and it might respond to messages for which it does not have a directly corresponding method.

Answer (score -1):

`dapptrace` (Dtrace) is your friend.

on the man page (`man dapptrace`):

> dapptrace prints details on user and
>   library function calls

`dapptrace` is written for the Dtrace scripting language (`D`).  This means you can adjust dapptrace or pull ideas from it's script file to do many things.  For instance:

wait for `myFunctionWhichCreatesSpecialObject` to be called.  Store the object address that it returns (the special object).  Print out any selectors invoked on that object.

You can also invoke dtrace directly to write simple single-line spells.  I'll let you go search for those.

Answer (score -2):

During runtime you would use

the class method "+ (BOOL)instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)aSelector"

provided you know the selectors you want to check on.