# How to enumerate methods of a class

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-runtime

Is there any way to enumerate methods of one class, 
for example, I have one class defined like below:

```
@class Foo : NSObject
    -(void)doStuff1;
    -(void)doStuff2;
@end
```

And I was wondering if there is any way let me access the method "doStuff1" and "doStuff2" with enumerate methods, even before I know the class has two methods.

I know the method `[foo performSelector:@selector(doSutff1)]` but this is not I want.
Pls any guy tell me the way, thx so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List selectors for obj-c object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330030/list-selectors-for-obj-c-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the runtime library...

```
class_copyMethodList
```

Check the Apple docs [**here**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)