# iOS Jailbroken devices development: How to dump method calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I am pretty new to development for iOS devices with jailbreak. From what I am reading I understand that to be able to do all the cool things which you can't do on non-jailbroken phones you have to hook up to a given class and override some of its behaviour. Since there is no documentation how a developer tracks to which class exactly he should hook?
I imagine that for instance if I wanted to have my app respond to a given event such as phone boot, call hang up or user clicking on an icon I would manually generate the given event and see what invocations have been made. Is this the proper way to track where you should hook your code and if yes how is it done.
Note I am not interested in exactly those events mentioned above I am more interested the approach in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches:

- Disassemble binaries

You can disassemble a binary or just dump classes with something like class-dump.
So, you can see the whole hierarhy of classes.

- Find dumped classes

Most of major iOS subsystems were dissasembled by somebody already. You can find quite a lot of useful stuff.

As example. Google search "Springboard headers" got [this](https://github.com/peterhajas/SpringBoard-4.x-Headers)

- Dump classes in a runtime.

Look at this question for explanation: [List selectors for Objective-C object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330030/list-selectors-for-obj-c-object)

Comment: ok this seems like a good idea to dump selectors an object responds to. How do you dump classes and objects at runtime. Can I dump all selector calls / objects at runtime and from there reverse engineer? If yes how to do it?

Comment: I don't think that you can dump list of all classes/objects at runtime (at least I didn't see anything like it). I saw only how to dump selectors for an object or an class (which is described at List selectors link in the answer)

Comment: I believe you can dump all classes for a NSBundle in runtime. Look at this link: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/191013-getting-list-of-classes-inside-nsbundle.html

Comment: thanks, I am getting my jailbroken device soon so this should be a decent starting point. I will keep the thread opened for some time for maybe expand on this once I get the chance to test this.