# List the selectors an instance of a class responds to

Tags: objective-c, reflection, runtime, selector

Is it possible to get a list of all the selectors that an instance of a given class responds to?

Comment: See the stackoverflow article describing [class_copyMethodList][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330030/list-selectors-for-obj-c-object

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [copyMethodList()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyMethodList) returns a list of the implemented methods. There are potentially more selectors, the instance will respond to by using the forwarding mechanism.

class_copyMethodList() copies only the methods implemented at this stage of the class hierarchy. To get all you have to iterate up the superclasses:

```
Class class = object_getClass( instance );
while( class != Nil )
{
   // copy method list 
   class = class_getSuperclass( class );
}
```

Comment: This is not strictly the list of selectors a class responds to; a class can respond in other ways than by implementing a method with the same name -- by forwarding or by resolving a selector at runtime.

Comment: That's correct, it is only the list of methods. But there is no way to find out to which selectors a class' instance responds, if a method is not implemented. But in most cases this is not relevant. Anyway I added a clarification.

Comment: Yes; as far as I know you would have to get a list of all the selectors registered with the runtime and ask the instance about every one of them -- and that list isn't public, either.

Answer (score 0):

If the selectors are not hidden, you can type `[instanceName` (with a space after) and then hit `ESC`. A drop down will pop up giving you a list of visible selectors.